# Vectors and Multithreading with Unity

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

This is a short one that I have been unable to google a clear answer for.

Basically, I’m working with pixels but I want to put it on a second thread so UI and everything runs during expensive operations.

Are `Vector4`s, which are implicitly convertable to and from `Color`, allowed on other threads even though Unity isn’t thread safe?

Basically, how would I go about doing color operations without `Color` struct or `Vector4`s (if those don’t work either)?

Comment: Define "thread safe". Without a [mcve], it's impossible to know whether your usage of the Unity3d vector types is thread safe. They don't have thread affinity, if that's what you mean. But if you are modifying a vector value in two different threads or using it in one thread while you modify it in another, that could be a problem. Or it might not. It depends on the code. Which you didn't provide. Please also read [ask] for more information about how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: **YES!** (as long as you don't read/write them at the same time of course).

---

In long:

Only those parts that directly require or influence the Scene itself are not usable from any other threads than the Unity "main" thread. Unity immediately blocks it and shows a warning. So what you can not do is e.g. setting or getting `Transform` properties, trying to access `.gameObject` on any `Component`, anything related to `Texture2D`, stuff like `GetComponent`, `Find` etc.

`struct`s, however, like [`Vector4`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector4.cs), [`Color`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Color.cs), [`Quaternion`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Quaternion.cs) etc are just basic data containers holding some values and doing some pure mathematical operations on them ... they can be used in any background thread in order to process them.

Even your own `MonoBehaviour` can possibly be used in background threads (you just pass in a reference) as long as you access only those fields and only call those methods, that - again - don't immediately require or influence the Scene.

However, they are not "thread-safe" themselves, meaning there is no `lock` going on. So of course you have to **assure yourself** that your threads (Unity main thread and background thread(s)) have **exclusive access** to your values, meaning only exactly one thread may be reading and writing at the same time.

Something like this is completely valid:

```
private IEnumerator Start ()
{
    Debug.Log("MainThread: Let's get some colors");
    var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Restart();
    var thread = new Thread(ColorThread);
    thread.Start();

    while (!ColorsReceived())
    {
        Debug.Log("MainThread: ... still waiting ...");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    }

    lock(_lock)
    {
        Debug.Log($"MainThread: Got {colors.Length} colors after {stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000f} seconds");
    }
}

private bool ColorsReceived()
{
    lock(_lock)
    {
        return colors != null;
    }
}

private void ColorThread()
{
    Debug.Log("BackgroundThread: Started generating colors");
    var output = new Color[1000];
    var random = new System.Random();
    for(var i = 0; i < output.Length;i++)
    {
        output[i] = new Color32((byte) random.Next(0, 256), (byte) random.Next(0, 256), (byte) random.Next(0, 256), (byte)random.Next(0,256));
    }

    // Do some havy stuff
    Thread.Sleep(3000);

    lock(_lock)
    {
        colors = output;
    }
    
    Debug.Log("BackgroundThread: Finished generating colors");
}
```

=>

```
MainThread: Lets's get some colors
MainThread: ... still waiting ...
BackgroundThread: Started generating colors
MainThread: ... still waiting ...
MainThread: ... still waiting ...
MainThread: ... still waiting ...
MainThread: ... still waiting ...
BackgroundThread: Finished generating colors
MainThread: Got 1000 colors after 3.19 seconds
```